# Pitch shift in typescript

Tags: typescript, webassembly, assemblyscript, pitch-shifting, audioworkletprocessor

I am trying to develop a webassembly function that can shift the pitch from and audioworklet. I have the wasm module compiling(assemblyscript) and working from the worklet, but can't seem to get my pitch shift algorithm to work correctly. Is there somewhere I can start looking for some references on logic I can use for this?

Comment: I’m afraid your question is a bit too general - you cannot get it to work correctly? In what way? What does it do at the moment?

Comment: @ColinE To expand on what I was saying. I can't get it to work, meaning, I have a function that works if I use it straight in the audioworklet itself. When I transcribe it to assemblyscript(typescript) it no longer works. I assume it has something to do with adding types. When using it through wasm, it sounds very staticy(I guess is the way to put it). I can't use the regular audioworklet setup that was working for me because this is part of a multi track system where there could be however many instances of the worklet. After about 5-10 tracks, the sound starts to break down.